# debugging windows service: breakpoint will not currently be hit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-services, visual-studio-debugging

I have attached the process for my windows service which is running/started on my machine. In vs.net 2010 I have a few breakbpoints set in my service, but each of them says?:

'break point will not currently be hit'

what is the easiest way to get the debugging for windows services happening?

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct way to debug the windows service but you should be sure that the files of the windows service are updated. I mean that whenever you build the windows service project you should stop the service, replace the windows service exe and the related dlls and then restart the windows service.

Comment: Yes.. I also suspect that in this case source code is different from service and so it is not able to hit the break point

Comment: Make sure that you are building your project in Debug mode and not release mode

Comment: Make sure that you have updated the pdb files together with your exe files.

Comment: Thank you Ghyath, I don't know why the original poster failed to mark your response as an answer so I will. This helped me out!